# ConTeXt: Protrusion does not work with the \quotation macro

Tags: macros, context, protrusion

For some reason, protrusion is not applied when using the `\quotation` macro. See the following example:

```
\setuppapersize[S3]
\showframe

\definefontfeature [default] [default] [protrusion=quality]
\setupalign[hanging]

\starttext
  “Protrusion works with regular text quotation marks.”
  \blank
  \quotation{But the \type{\quotation} macro breaks the effect on the quotes.}
  \blank
  ‘Same with single quotes…’
  \blank
  \quote{…and the \type{\quote} macro.}
\stoptext
```

[image: rendered PDF]

Why is this happening? How can I fix this without having the write the quotes by hand?

**EDIT:** `\define[1]\myquotation{“#1”}` works, but it’s a bit of a hack.

Comment: See this in the mailing list: https://www.mail-archive.com/ntg-context@ntg.nl/msg97133.html. The alternative proposed is to use `\setupquotation[method=font]
\setupquote[method=font]`. Does this work for you?

Comment: It works perfectly, thank you! I wonder why it’s not the default. I have to up my game when it comes to searching through the mailing list.